# Generate testng reports without overwriting the previous test output result?

Tags: maven, report, testng

I am using selenium-webdriver using java. I am using testNG, after executing I get the default report. But once I re-run the suite the previous results get over written.

Can we generate testng reports without overwriting the previous test output result?

Do we need any build tool? If yes how to do it with maven?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you could generate reports without overwriting previous.

To achieve it you need to parametrize report output directory.

I don't know, how to do it with pure TestNG, but with maven-surefire-plugin it's quite simple:

```
<plugins>
    <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
        <configuration>
            <suiteXmlFiles>
                <suiteXmlFile>testng-suite.xml</suiteXmlFile>
            </suiteXmlFiles>
            <reportsDirectory>report_${maven.build.timestamp}</reportsDirectory>
        </configuration>
    </plugin>
</plugins>
```

This will create separate directory for each run using current timestamp as unique suffix.

Answer (score 0):

If you have a path to the directory you are storing the report, and want to keep past reports for future reference you can time stamp the name of the report

```
   Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();   
   Date time=cal.getTime();
   String timestamp=time.toString();
   String systime=timestamp.replace(":", "-");
   int year = cal.get(Calendar.YEAR);
   int month = (cal.get(Calendar.MONTH)+1);
   int day = cal.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);



   public void generateReport  (List<XmlSuite> xmlSuites, List<ISuite> suites, String outputDirectory) {
    extent = new ExtentReports("C:\\XAMPP\\htdocs\\TestReports\\TestReport" + " " + systime + "_" + Constants.U360_VERSION +".html");
```